# Erro na passagem de parâmetro Java

Tags: java

Estou começando a aprender Java e estou com um problema em um código simples que fiz. É um programa que lê uma entrada de texto e depois imprime na tela, porém ao tentar compilar ocorre esse erro aqui

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
>
> The method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)
>
> at Beginning.GradeBookTest.main(GradeBookTest.java:30)

Classe GradeBook:

```
package Beginning;
//Declaração de classe com um método

public class GradeBook {
    
    public String courseName; //Nome do curso para esse GradeBook
    
    //Método para configurar o nome do curso
    public void setCourseName(String name){
        courseName = name;//Armazena o nome do curso
    }//Fim do método setCourseName
    
    //Método para recuperar o nome do curso
    public String getCourseName(){
        return courseName;
    }//Fim do método getCourseName
    
    //Exibe uma mensagem de boas-vindas para o usuário GradeBook
    
    public void displayMessage(){
        /*Chama getCourseName para obter o nome do
         * curso que essa GradeBook representa*/
        System.out.printf("Welcome to the GradeBook for\n%s!\n", getCourseName());
    }
} //Fim da classe GradeBook
```

Classe do main:

```
package Beginning;
import java.util.Scanner; //Importando a função Scanner
//Criando um objeto GradeBookTest e chamando seu método displayMessage
public class GradeBookTest {
    
    public static void main (String[] args){
        //Cria Scanner para obter entrada a partir da janela de comando
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        //Cria um objeto GradeBook e o atribui a myGradeBook
        GradeBook myGradeBook = new GradeBook();
        
        //Exibe o valor inicial de courseName
        System.out.printf("Initial course name is: %s\n\n", myGradeBook.getCourseName());
        
        //Solicita e lê o nome do curso
        System.out.println("Please, enter the course name: ");
        String theName = input.nextLine();//Lê uma linha de texto
        myGradeBook.setCourseName(theName);//Configura o nome do curso
        System.out.println();//Gera saída de uma linha em branco
        /*Exibe mensagem de boas-vindas depois 
         * de especificar o nome do curso*/
        myGradeBook.displayMessage();
    }//Fim de main
} //Fim da classe GradeBookTest
```

Comment: O problema deve ser em outro lugar, aqui "funcionou": https://ideone.com/nBO5JV

Comment: Também rodei no NetBeans 8.2 e funcionou.

Comment: Consegui resolver! Era problema no compilador. Eu estava usando o 1.4 e alterei para o 1.6. Para alterar é só ir em window -> preferences -> java -> compiler.